# How does Wildfly perform Session replication?

Tags: session, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, session-replication

The main problem is I am unable to implement session replication in a two node cluster and in a domain configuration (master + slave).
There are no errors whatsover in the logs but that's for another question.

Right now;
Researching lead me to these questions:

- Does Wildfly/JBoss do session replication using Infinispan only ?
- If not then what is the mechanism ?

How does session replication work in JBoss ?

Comment: Domain mode is how you manage many servers,  you probably actually want to run he or standalone-full-ha

Comment: But in domain mode replication works no ?

Comment: It is possible in domain mode, but I don't think domain mode gives you the "ha" stuff you need for replication by default

Comment: So you're saying I should have standalone mode for session replication?

Comment: If all you want is two nodes that replicate, then running standalone ha is what you want, domain would be overkill

Comment: ahan,  Okay Great I'll Try that Then

Comment: But domain should allow session replication

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/WildFly+9+Cluster+Howto